Amadeus hotel-search endpoint returning "INVALID PROPERTY CODE" for existing properties
I'm having an issue with the hotel-search endpoint. I get 'invalid property code' for almost all requests. I double checked the hotelId I send out, and it even works fine if I look for the hotel by ID, but will return 'invalid property code' if I try to get offers for the same hotel.
Example:
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-hotels?hotelIds=LXMILGRY (works fine)
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v3/shopping/hotel-offers?hotelIds=LXMILGRY&adults=1&checkInDate=2024-11-24&checkOutDate=2024-11-25&roomQuantity=1&paymentPolicy=NONE&bestRateOnly=true
Returns:
{
  "code": 1257,
  "title": "INVALID PROPERTY CODE",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Provider Error - INVALID PROPERTY CODE",
  "source": {
    "parameter": "hotelIds=LXMILGRY"
  }
}

Any clue what I might be doing wrong?
